# Script asking for confirmation despite using -y

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts

I am trying to develop a script to setup software and some firewall rules. This is run on a fresh VPS while connected via SSH as the root user.

There are 2 points in the script where it appears to ignore '-y'

**First Item:**

`apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt autoremove -y && apt autoclean -y`

Causes this prompt to occur: [Restart services during package upgrades without asking?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCb2y.png) Which I would like to just automatically select Yes.

**Second Item:**

```
ufw allow 1635/udp
ufw allow ssh
ufw enable
```

Causes this prompt to occur: [Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg4Li.png) Which I would also like to just automatically select Yes.

Any help would be much appreciated. These 2 items are currently stopping it from being a completely hands-off setup process.

Comment: `man apt-get` shows a -y option; `man apt` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

**First Item**

Discovered it was the `apt upgrade` causing the GUI prompt.
This was resolved by updating it to: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -y`

**Second Item**

Resolved by updating `ufw enable` to: `yes | ufw enable`

Comment: Its good to hear that your issue has been resolved :)

You can mark your answer as the solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:
`$echo -e "\t Yes"`
at the end as this should traverse to `<Yes>` in terminal for your first issue.
OR
`$echo "\t \r"` at the end for same issue.

**AND**
For your second issue try this:

`$ echo "y" | sudo ufw enable`

Comment: *First Item*
I've figured out that it is something during the ```apt upgrade``` command that raises that prompt. I have tried both:
```apt upgrade -y```
```echo -e "\t Yes"```
or 
```apt upgrade -y```
```echo "\t \r"```
Both unfortunately don't seem to work and cause the prompt to still appear and require a manual selection.

*Second Item*
This has been resolved by changing the line to ```yes | ufw enable```
Thank you!